# Typescript approach for ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this)

Tags: typescript, knockout-mapping-plugin

How to address following error 'mapping' implicitly has an 'any' type on

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this)
```

In addition, when I reference a property of the dynamic object from the 'fromJS' i get error that property 'currentView' does not exist on type of object.

```
viewModel.WorkOrderClient.currentView()
```

Comment: I do not know knockout but there must be a problem with the definition files. As a poor man's workaround can you try : `(ko.mapping as any).fromJs(...)` ?

Comment: So after I moved ko.mapping into the constructor I was good.  I believe taht was an issue with not finding data variable.

With respect to (part2) if I use ko.mapping.fromJS it creates an observable object however if i reference any properties typescript is not aware of this...

Right now...I had to create an interface for WorkOrderClient and define WorkOrderClient as a public via

    public WorkOrderClient: IWorkOrderClient;  is this the best approach for dealing with dynamic objects in typescript?